# Two totally different frontend users ￼in Yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I'm developing an application using the advanced Yii2 template.

I already have two different sessions separated for backend and frontend users. 
My main.php files are like this:

```
// frontend/config/main.php
...
'user' => [
    'identityClass'   => 'common\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
...

// backend/config/main.php
...
'user' => [
    'identityClass'   => 'backend\models\BEUser',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
...
```

I am facing problems when I try to implement a **second separate frontend user**. Right now, when I login for the different user model, I'm logged in as a regular frontend user as well.

I don't want to use RBAC, because I want the two different kinds of users **fully separate**. Which means, different database tables, different session names, different login pages, and access to totally different parts and pages of the website.

I think of adding a separate "user2" entry in frontend/config/main.php, but I cannot find any similar guide on the internet. So I assume this is something not possible.

Do you have any suggestions for that? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why not add a second frontend as well?

Comment: I've thought of this. It seems not very worth the effort though. I need the second user only for one or two separate pages. Creating a separate frontend with different configuration, controllers, etc, I don't know, seems too much effort. There must be another way.

Comment: *'different database tables, different session names, different login pages, and access to totally different parts and pages of the website'*. Seems worth the effort considering all of the above. Easier to test and maintain too.

Comment: OK. Can you suggest a small guide or a small how-to on the internet, about creating a different frontend area in yii2?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tested this, however you might be able to do it by creating a `user2` in your frontend create a `LoginForm2` model that instead of using `user` component it uses `user2` component to do the login.

**frontend config:**

```
'user2' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\User',
    'identityClass'   => 'common\models\User2',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

**LoginForm2.php:**

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user2->login($this->getUser(), 1800);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: By implementing the above, I'm facing a "Setting unknown property: common\models\User2::identityClass" error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tested the code you posted? Unfortunately this does not work either. When I login with a user2 account, I also have access as a regular user in other parts of the website that I don't want to.